# TypeError: undefined is not a function ('..._this.setState...')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm beginner in React Native (and programming in general), currently trying out a simple location component using google maps API. As I'm trying to fetch the position coordinates to be used with the Map view, I am stuck on the following error.

> TypeError: undefined is not a function ('..._this.setState...')

My code:

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import FetchLocation from './components/FetchLocation';
import UsersMap from './components/UsersMap';

export default function App() {
  state = {
    userLocation: null
  }

  getUserLocationHandler=()=> {
    console.log('Pressed the button');
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
      console.log(position);
      this.setState({
        userLocation:{
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.2922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.2421
        }
      })

    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FetchLocation onGetLocation={this.getUserLocationHandler}/>
      <UsersMap userLocation={this.state.userLocation}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Any ideas in helping me spot the issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've mixed the syntax of class based components within a function component. A class based component is declared with `class App extends React.Component { /**/ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` is part of the [API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) provided to react's class components, and can be used **only** if you create a class component and extend `React.Component`. You can find out more about class components and `React.Component` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#overview).

That said, I strongly recommend you to take a look on [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) if you are using react version > 16.8, as they provide the ability to use state without the need of creating a class component.

For your code to work properly, you just need to make it a class component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import FetchLocation from './components/FetchLocation';
import UsersMap from './components/UsersMap';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    userLocation: null
  }

  getUserLocationHandler() {
    console.log('Pressed the button');
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
      console.log(position);
      this.setState({
        userLocation:{
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.2922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.2421
        }
      })

    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FetchLocation onGetLocation={this.getUserLocationHandler}/>
        <UsersMap userLocation={this.state.userLocation}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

or to use `useState` hook:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import FetchLocation from './components/FetchLocation';
import UsersMap from './components/UsersMap';

export default function App() {
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);

  const getUserLocationHandler = () => {
    console.log('Pressed the button');
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
      console.log(position);
      setUserLocation({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.2922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.2421
      })

    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FetchLocation onGetLocation={getUserLocationHandler}/>
      <UsersMap userLocation={userLocation}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: `onGetLocation={getUserLocationHandler}` would be enough since it's already an arrow function created just above.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have `state` in a function component you need to use the [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). The way you implemented `state` and also the `setState` method is exclusive to class components. Please refer to the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

On a related note, the `this` keyword will also never work in a function component.

Answer (score 1):

`.setState` is for class based components only. Your component is functional. Look into React Hooks, specifically `useState` hook to learn about how to have a state in a functional component.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use useState React hook, in this case defining your state will be something like this :
`[userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null)`
then to set your state you need to use setUserLocation like this 
`setUserLocation({new location object})`